# Get path points on applied impulse

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added impulse to GameObject like

```
rigidbody.Addforce( SomeVector3, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

and my gravity multiplier is 4. How to calculate points of my path before I apply that impuls on body ?
I have all data like mass, gravity multipiler and so on and I would like to draw that path before apply impulse so I need number of points.

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, it would be helpful for others if you accept that answer. If not, feel free to comment on the answers given, or update your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using common physics you are of course able to predict the path the object will go. The problem is, your formulas, ticking etc. will most likely not **exactly** be the same as the ones Unity uses internally, so your results won't be exact.

Only thing I can think off is having a second, invisible, version of your GameObject and apply the impulse to it and track its position, then display the resulting path for your visible GameObject. You might consider accelerating Unity's time using `Time.timeScale` during prediction, so you don't have to wait too long for the simulation's results.

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted to suggest. +1. Even that this  tracking gets time, coould be good for nice drawing of the path lets say with trail component.